# Probability of passing

Tags: probability

It is known that out of two students only one will pass the exam is $0.023 = \mathbb P(U)$.
Calculate:
a) probabilities for the event $\mathbb P(B)$ that the second student will pass the exam, if this probability is $0.3=\mathbb P(A)$ for the first.

b) probabilities for the event that at least one of the students will pass the exam. $\mathbb P(C)$

In my opinion:

a) $\mathbb P(U)=\mathbb P(A)(1-\mathbb P(B)) + (1-\mathbb P(A))\mathbb P(B) = 0.023$ and from this express $\mathbb P(B)$.
$\mathbb P(B)=0.548 \text{ or } 0.052$ but how to choose which one is correct.

b) $\mathbb P(C)=\mathbb P(U)+\mathbb P(B)\mathbb P(A)=$?

Comment: Your idea for a) is correct, but I don't understand how you get those solutions for $p(B)$. It is given that $p(A)=0.3$ and $1-p(A)=0.7$. Let $x:=p(B)$ for simplicity. Then we have $0.3(1-x)+0.7x=0.023$ which results in $x=-0.6925$, which is not possible. Are you sure that you got the numbers right?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, I found a mistake. Then b) it remains to insert the specified value. @vitamind

Comment: The teacher made a mistake in the conditions of the task. But thank you! $\mathbb P(U)$ should be 0.32, and x=0.05

Comment: A linear equation cannot have two solutions.